# How do put a chrome:// link in a chrome extension

Tags: json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

i want to make a chrome extension that would change the content of chrome://newtab.
But when i put it in the matches selector, it gives an invalid scheme error. How could i fix this?

```js
{
  ... //name
  ... //version
  ... //manifest version
  
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["chrome://newtab"],
      "css": ...
      "js": ...
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: You can't. See [chrome content scripts and newtab](//stackoverflow.com/a/45659562) and use [Chrome URL overrides](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/override) instead.

Comment: well dammit, thanks for the answer though.